# Timer reset at every refresh in web page

Tags: javascript, html

My page contains a timer, and whenever a refresh is made, it starts from beginning.

If any one can help me by telling that how can previous time be retained, even if refresh is made, by giving an example.

Comment: When does the timer start?

Comment: You can use a cookie or local storage to save the previous value of the timer and read from it when the page is refreshed.

Comment: What is the timer based on? what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [HTML5 Local Web storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to store that value, using JavaScript:

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");

localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

Answer (score -1):

An idea:

Store the current time in the "onunload"-event of the window/document in the "window.name"-property.
It is a bit hacky, but still useful if you won't struggle with cookies.

Comment: All you would need to store is the start time and target end-time, the rest can be calculated based on current time, right?

Comment: sure but this has to be done in navigation-aware way (window.name or cookie for example)... if you store START and DURATION or START and END-Time is totally equal